# Monitoring Tools for Kafka

Tags: monitoring, apache-kafka

I have my Kafka(0.9.0.0) Nodes and Zookeeper setup , i have 3 Kafka nodes and 3 zookeeper nodes and its is working absolutely fine.

Now i was looking for set of monitoring tools to monitor topics, load on each node, memory usage . Are there any good tools?

1) I have tried exploring Kafka-Manager -- but it only supports till 0.8.2.2 version.

2) Ganglia -  It gives an overview about some stuff but it put too much load on Kafka nodes, and needs to installed on each node.

3) Nagios - It work i will OK but doesn't provide much detail and it also needs to installed on each node.

So , What i was looking for is a tool that gives me insights about **health , performance , memory consumption, Notification if something goes wrong ,status of the node** and all other details for each Kafka and zookeeper nodes without needed to be installed on each nodes. I was planning to have a central Monitoring Server where i have all the tools which can be used for this .

What is the set of tool people use for monitoring their Kafka clusters??

Comment: Based on #4 of this list, http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, I would say that your question is off topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: https://medium.com/@giorgosmyrianthous/overview-of-ui-monitoring-tools-for-apache-kafka-clusters-9ca516c165bd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SPM for Kafka monitoring](https://sematext.com/spm/integrations/kafka-monitoring/) can do everything you mentioned.  It works with all recent versions of Kafka and pulls some 100-200 metrics.  You also mention ZooKeeper, which SPM can monitor for you, too.  Note that you will want to get the monitoring agent installed on each node. Why? Because you will want to get the OS metrics, too.